# asymptote multiple graphics in single file

Tags: floats, asymptote

One of the features I've liked in `metapost` and missed in `asymptote` is the fact that (in `metapost`) I can write the code for many figures in a single file. `metapost` then generates indexed set of figures once compiled. For documents with many figures this is very useful feature.
Can anyone confirm that this is not possible in asymptote.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by an "indexed set of figures". Are these files with names like `foo-1.eps`, `foo-2.eps`, etc.?

Comment: foo.1, foo.2 (with metapost these are not stand alone eps)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE, you can put as many figures in a single file as you wish but you'll need to draw each into a seperate `picture`, you can do this simply by creating a new `picture` object at the start of each figure and assigning it to `currentpicture`. For each figure, you'll need to explicitly call `shipout` with the desired output filename.

If you compile the following examples with `asy -f pdf` you'll end up with two files named `output01.pdf` and `output02.pdf`, one per figure.

```
// Figure 1
currentpicture=new picture; // For the first figure, you can skip this
import graph;

size(140mm,70mm,IgnoreAspect);
real[] x={1,3,4,5,6};
real[] y={1,5,2,0,4};
draw(graph(x,y,Hermite));
shipout("output01"); // save currentpicture to file named output01

currentpicture=new picture; // "clear the canvas"
size(140mm,70mm,IgnoreAspect);
real[] x2={1,2,3,4,5};
real[] y2={-3,1,9,2,4};
draw(graph(x2,y2,Hermite));
shipout("output02"); // save it
```